# C++11 uint types vs u_int

Tags: c++11, uint, cstdint

I just stumbled upon the type `u_int8_t` because it did not compile in Windows+MinGW (but compiled fine under Linux). According to [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) the C++11 standard defines the type `uint8_t`. I just used the latter and everything worked.

The questions that arised are:

1. Is there any difference between `u_int8_t` and `uint8_t`?
2. Is there a reason (besides legacy code) to use `u_int8_t`?
3. Is it safe to assume that `uint8_t` will be present if I use a C++11 compiler (on different OS or architectures)?
4. Are the answers to the above questions also valid for the other types (`intX_t` and `uintX_t`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<cstdint> vs <stdint.h>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642827/cstdint-vs-stdint-h)

Comment: No. The question you mention deals with the difference between `cstdint` and `stdint.h`. The type `u_int8_t` is defined in `sys/types.h`. But this header is usually not available in Windows and/or MinGW.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is there any difference between `u_int8_t` and `uint8_t`?

`u_int8_t` is just a very old name that was not standardised. Avoid it.

> Is there a reason (besides legacy code) to use `u_int8_t`?

Suicide by coworker.

> Is it safe to assume that `uint8_t` will be present if I use a C++11 compiler (on different OS or architectures)?

The C++ standard requires it to be present on all implementations that have an unsigned 8-bit type available (today that means everything that is not exotic).

> Are the answers to the above questions also valid for the other types (`intX_t` and `uintX_t`)?

Pretty much, yes.