# size of a hex pattern in cpp

Tags: c++, hex, sizeof

I have a hex pattern stored in a variable, how to do I know what is the size of the hex pattern
E.g. --

```
#define MY_PATTERN 0xFFFF
```

now I want to know the size of MY_PATTERN, to use somewhere in my code.

```
sizeof (MY_PATTERN)
```

this is giving me warning -- "integer conversion resulted in truncation".

How can I fix this ? What is the way I should write it ?

The pattern can increase or decrease in size so I can't hard code it.

Comment: So what *is* the "size" of `0xFFFF`?

Comment: I suspect the warning is coming from how you're using the result of the `sizeof()` expression, not the expression itself.

Comment: What is your allowed range for the pattern?

Comment: I can calculate the size man!!!

Please read it completely. I might change the defined pattern later and so if I use something like 2 bytes and later MY_PATTERN variable changes to 0xFFFFFFFF. What to do then ?

Comment: try this, no warning: #include <stdio.h>
int main () {
  #define  MY_PATTERN 0xFFFF
  size_t x=sizeof (MY_PATTERN);
  printf ("%u\n", x);
}

Comment: Hey, no set limit for pattern at least now so want to avoid hard coding an upper bound

Comment: @Siddharth: I 'm not sure you are getting the point. `0xFFFF` is an integer literal; *it already has* an upper bound.

Comment: @Jon: [It's `4`](http://ideone.com/UYNhwo) :-) (Depends on the compiler, I imagine.)

Comment: You should get familiar with the [sizes of various types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) in C++.

Comment: Can you tell which compiler etc you are using? Maybe the prog which brings up the warning....

Comment: are you wanting to find the appropriate type for the limit? e.g. 0xFF would be 1 byte, 0xFFFF would be 2 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it.

There's no such thing in C++ as a `"hex pattern"`. What you actually use is an [**integer literal**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). See paragraph `"The type of the literal"`. Thus, `sizeof (0xffff)` is equal to `sizeof(int)`. And the bad thing is: [**the exact size may vary.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/396583)

From the design point of view, I can't really think of a situation where such a solution is acceptable. You're not even deriving a type from a literal value, which would be a suspicious as well, but at least, a *typesafe* solution. Sizes of values are mostly used in operations working with memory buffers directly, like `memcpy()` or `fwrite()`. Sizes defined in such indirect ways lead to a very brittle binary interface and maintenance difficulties. What if you compile a program on both `x86` and `Motorola 68000` machines and want them to interoperate via a network protocol, or want to write some files on the first machine, and read them on another? `sizeof(int)` is 4 for the first and 2 for the second. It will break.

Instead, explicitly use the exactly sized types, like int8_t, uint32_t, etc. They're defined in the [`<cstdint>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642827/cstdint-vs-stdint-h) header.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem:

```
#define MY_PATTERN 0xFFFF

struct TypeInfo
{
    template<typename T>
    static size_t SizeOfType(T) { return sizeof(T); }
};

void main()
{
    size_t size_of_type = TypeInfo::SizeOfType(MY_PATTERN);
}
```

as pointed out by Nighthawk441 you can just do:

```
sizeof(MY_PATTERN);
```

Just make sure to use a size_t wherever you are getting a warning and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Why not just assign size_of_type = sizeof(MY_PATTERN) right away?

Comment: What is the purpose of the struct? What is the purpose of the template? This is way to complicated for what it does, and this will always return `sizeof(int)` for all integer values, so is probably not what the op wants?

Comment: This is why I dont like using #define and why I ensure I use size_t with sizeof.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly typedef various types to hold hex numbers with restricted sizes such that:

```
typedef unsigned char one_byte_hex;
typedef unsigned short two_byte_hex;
typedef unsigned int four_byte_hex;

one_byte_hex pattern = 0xFF;
two_byte_hex bigger_pattern = 0xFFFF;
four_byte_hex big_pattern = 0xFFFFFFFF;

//sizeof(pattern) == 1
//sizeof(bigger_pattern) == 2
//sizeof(biggest_pattern) == 4

four_byte_hex new_pattern = static_cast<four_byte_hex>(pattern);
//sizeof(new_pattern) == 4
```

It would be easier to just treat all hex numbers as unsigned ints regardless of pattern used though.

Alternatively, you could put together a function which checks how many times it can shift the bits of the pattern until it's 0.

```
size_t sizeof_pattern(unsigned int pattern)
{
    size_t bits = 0;
    size_t bytes = 0;
    unsigned int tmp = pattern;

    while(tmp >> 1 != 0){
        bits++;
        tmp = tmp >> 1;
    }
    bytes = (bits + 1) / 8; //add 1 to bits to shift range from 0-31 to 1-32 so we can divide properly. 8 bits per byte.
    if((bits + 1) % 8 != 0){
        bytes++; //requires one more byte to store value since we have remaining bits.
    }
    return bytes;
}
```