# Strange errors when using c++11 features in qt creator (mingw 4.8 and qt 5.3)

Tags: qt, c++11, mingw, qt-creator, mingw32

I want to use c++11 in my project in qt creator.I have tried to add c++11 support by adding one of the following to .pro file :

```
 CONFIG += c++11
```

or

```
 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

But none of them works for me, and after adding these to .pro file, the compiler (mingw 4.8) give me a lot of errors like :

> *C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/cstdint:48:11:
>   error: '::int8_t' has not been declared*    *using ::int8_t;*
>             *^*
>
> *C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/cstdint:49:11:
>   error: '::int16_t' has not been declared*    *using ::int16_t;*
>              *^*
>
> *C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/cstdint:50:11:
>   error: '::int32_t' has not been declared    using ::int32_t;
>              ^*
>
> *C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/cstdint:51:11:
>   error: '::int64_t' has not been declared*    *using ::int64_t;*
>              *^*
>
> *C:/Qt/Qt5.3.2/Tools/mingw482_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/cstdint:53:11:
>   error: '::int_fast8_t' has not been declared*    *using
>   ::int_fast8_t;*

What is the problem??!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `cstdint`, you have to provide need a `using` for these types.

Insert

```
using ::int8_t;
using ::int16_t;
using ::int32_t;
using ::int64_t;
using ::int_fast8_t;
```

(and everything else that's reported missing) into your source file(s), where these errors occur.

There's more on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642827/cstdint-vs-stdint-h).

Comment: Downvote because the answer is wrong. The quote in the question clearly shows that errors are originating from within `<cstdint>`, and exactly in the corresponding `using` statements within that header. With respect to the linked answer; MinGW has one of those many implementations of `<cstdint>` where just the C-header is included, polluting the global namespace, and then lifted into the `std::` namespace using a `using` directive. The problem here is that somehow the C-header does not define those types. I have the same problem 6 years later, and would love a correct answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most common case for this error is that you are including standard library headers *inside* a namespace of you own. (do not do that ;)

example:

```
namespace my_space {
   #include <cstdint>
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bP7TnWP1s