# Unknown type name uint64_t and uint16_t uint8_t in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to compile a program in Ubuntu environment but I'm having some error saying `unknown type name 'uint64_t'`, `unknown type name 'uint16_t'` even though I have included `cstdint` and any other requirements I believe. It seems like the C++ library support issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please include your code, showing the #include.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to use `std::uint64_t`, but can't be certain without the code.  Is the code `using namespace std;` ?  - Actually, just read this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13643019/1730895

Comment: Please add your code, and the command used for compiling along with the environment details.

Comment: This linked code does *not* include `<cstdint>` or `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your code there.

Comment: you don't post the full code. You need to create a [mcve] which demonstrates your problem

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is it the native compiler from `apt-get` or `yum`; or is it something else?? Does it need a `-sysroot` , and is it set?

Answer (score 7):

Without seeing your code it's very hard to answer.  I *guess* the code does not include `cstdint` or `stdint.h`, and/or it is not using the `std::uint64_t` syntax.

So my answer can only be a simple test/example you can run.

Compile it with:

```
g++ -Wall -g --std=c++11 int64_test.cpp -o int64_test -lstdc++
```

The Code "int64_test.cpp":

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    std::uint64_t u64 = 3;
    std::int32_t  i32 = 141;

    std::cout << "u64 = " << u64 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "i32 = " << i32 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code & compilation works fine on Ubuntu 18.04.  I expect it will also work on Ubuntu 14.x

For the sake of completeness, a C version (since this is(was) tagged into the question too)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>  // Must have this!

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    uint64_t u64 = 3;
    int32_t  i32 = 141;

    printf( "u64 = %lu\n", u64 );
    printf( "i32 = %d\n", i32 );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you include `<stdint.h>`, the names should be declared in the global namespace.

If you include `<cstdint>`, an implementation will declare them in the `std::` namespace, as `std::uint8_t`, etc.  It is allowed, but not required, to also declare them without the `std::` prefix.  (Pedantically, an implementation for some architecture with a weird word size would be allowed to have no `int64_t`, and only declare `int_least54_t` and `int_fast64_t`, but none that I know of actually do.)

I usually `#include <stdint.h>`.  However, a more fashionable way to do it might be:

```
#include <cstdint>

using std::uint8_t, std::uint16_t, std::uint64_t;
```